# OpenLayers 3 Vector layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

Can i add two sources to Vector layer, i want regular feature source, and geojson source?

Maybe can I do something like:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: VectorSource, GeoJsonSource});
```

My reason why i need to sources to one Vector layer because i have two different sources to load the features geojson and regular lat long.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new source and add features from both sources to this new source, then pass this source to your layer

```
var featuresToPass = VectorSource.getFeatures().concat(GeoJsonSource.getFeatures());
var mysource = new ol.source.Vector({
//using a collection the features in the source and the collection will stay in sync
features: featuresToPass //new ol.Collection(featuresToPass) 
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source:mysource});
```

I have not test it.

Comment: i don't see how does it answer my quesiton... i need two different soruces to the same Layer..

Comment: Obviously you can not attach 2 sources in the same layer. Read the docs if you want to be sure. I suggest you a way to overcome it. If you think it doesnt answer to your question , dont worry you dont have to pay.